# What is the formula of Median Magnitude of Relative Error? (MdMRE)

Tags: regression, cross-validation, validation, statsmodels

I'm familiar with these terms

1 - MRE Mean Relative Error

2 - MMRE Mean Magnitude of Relative Error

I need to compute MdMRE which is Median Mean Relative Error. I searched on the net but didn't find its formula. Any help related to this formula will be appreciated.

Comment: Editing your question to give some context would help a lot here. What are you computing the MRE/MMRE *of*? Why do you need to compute MdMRE? And 'Median Mean Relative Error' or 'Median Magnitude of Relative Error'? The former suggests taking the median of a set of means; the latter taking the median of a set of magnitudes (rather than taking the mean as in MRE).